# print something if the Yes Button is clicked in QMessageBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I'm Using PyQt5 and I've created a QMessagebox and I want to print something if the Yes Button is clicked. 
Here's my code

```
self.messageBox = QMessageBox()
self.messageBox.setText("Are You Sure with Left Edge You Chosed?")
self.messageBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
if self.messageBox == QMessageBox.Yes:
    self.confirmation = 1
    print("Yess Clicked")
else:
    self.confirmation = 0
self.messageBox.exec()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing the `QMessageBox` widget with `QMessageBox.Yes` that makes no sense. If you want to get the standardButton associated with the button pressed then you must use the [`standardButton()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#standardButton) and [`clickedButton()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#clickedButton) method:

```
self.messageBox = QMessageBox()
self.messageBox.setText("Are You Sure with Left Edge You Chosed?")
self.messageBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
self.messageBox.exec_()

if self.messageBox.standardButton(self.messageBox.clickedButton()) == QMessageBox.Yes:
    self.confirmation = 1
    print("Yess Clicked")
else:
    self.confirmation = 0
```

Comment: Yes, it is working good, but just for the information in PyQt6 the "exec_" is not defined, instead we can use "self.messageBox.exec()"